# VGA monitor no longer recognised on MacMini

Tags: macos, display, high-sierra, mac-mini, vga-adapter

I have a late 2012 MacMini. I was previously running with two old VGA monitors both using adapters from HRMI/DP ports on the Mac.

I replaced them with a large, QHD monitor running off the DP/Thunderbolt port. When I wanted to add one back using an HDMI->VGA converter, it doesn't work... the monitor light flashes to indicate no connection, nothing shows up in display settings.

I've tried multiple cables and adapters which as far as I know are all good.

In the intervening time, the changes to my system are:

- add the large Dell QHD monitor
- upgrade the OS from Mavericks to High Sierra

Could it be an OS issue?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE** I looked at "about my Mac" and saw it *is* listing the 2nd one... plugging it in and removing it my screen momentarily blanks as if it were working... but nothing is shown on the screen:

[image]

On Windows you can set the 2nd screen as pair/extend/replace the main one... I see no option on MacOS but is it *possible* I just need to enable screen sharing to this monitor somehow?

Though it claims it sees both monitors, nowhere can I see the SyncMaster in order to change its settings.

Comment: Have you tried removing the new monitor and attempting to verify that the old monitor still works?

Comment: What exact model of MacBook are you using? Your MacBook might not be able to handle that amount of pixels.

Comment: @KevinGrabher updated with more info. I'm pretty sure it should be able to drive QHD and HD through the two ports... I seem to recall reading about people doing this.

Comment: @Mr.Boy according to your screenshots we are talking about a Mac mini, not a MacBook? If the screenshot is right it should support up to two displays at 2560 by 1600 pixels => https://support.apple.com/kb/sp659?locale=en_US

Have you tried different adapters and cables, maybe even a diff. monitor to check if it is actually the Mac Mini making the issue?

Comment: Also I believe HDMI -> VGA is not possible on the Mac Mini as the port does not transport an analogue signal (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3682821). Are you sure this worked before? Could you alternatively use DVI on the SyncMaster or possibly HDMI for the Dell and the Mini Displayport for the SyncMaster?

Comment: Everything is probably set to be mirrored.  Go into *Displays Preferences* and set the resolution to 1280x1024.  Make sure you set to extend your desktop.

Comment: @KevinGrabher how embarrassing I don't know why I said MacBook... question edited now. My research showed this model only supports up to 1200p on HDMI, though the newer model removes that restriction.